# What is the "database name" for redis-insight?

Tags: redis, redisinsights

I'm running **Redis** via *docker-compose* and **redis-insights** for getting a UI.

Redis-Insight asks for a *"Logical Name of the redis database"* as a mandatory text field.
I tried things like "0", "1", "db0", "db1", "@0" but nothing will be accepted, although Redis can be used properly by my application via `redis://127.0.0.1:6389`.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6389:6379'
    expose:
      - 6389
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  cache-redis-insight:
    image: redislabs/redisinsight:latest
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical name is not the issue, thats just some name so you can identify which database you're connecting to, it doesnt exist on the redis server.

The actual problem is that `redisinsight` needs to connect to redis *from inside its container* while only your host can access `localhost:6389`

From inside the docker network your `redisinsight` container can connect to redis on `redis:6379`.  I just ran `docker compose up` and it works, Ill attach some pics.

[image]

[image]